# Retrieving data from code mirror after merge

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using code mirror instance to merge data. I want to retrieve the left hand side data from code mirror after performing the merge.
Code below:

```
$timeout(function () {
 var a = document.getElementById("diffView");
 dv = CodeMirror.MergeView(a, {
        value: repositoryData,
        orig: workspaceData,
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "javascript",
        highlightDifferences: true
    });
},1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the way out by using dv.editor().getValue();